# Java paintComponent wont be called upon repainting with invokelater

Tags: java, swing

I am using invoke later like this in my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Game bird = new Game();
            bird.initialize();
        }
    });
}
```

And then when I try to repaint, it won't call the paintComponent(Graphics g) in my JPanel.
But if I remove the invoke later, and just do new Game, it works fine?

This is how I do it:

```
private void gameLoop() {
    while(this.game) {
        this.update();
        this.render();
    }
}

private void update() {
    // TODO UPDATRES
}

private void render() {
    super.repaint();
}
```

And before the program sets the gui to visible, I add the component using super.add(Screen screen) and then set visible, this is my screen class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Screen extends JPanel {

    private Game game;

    public Screen(Game bird) {
        this.game = bird;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("hey");
    }
}
```

Why won't repaint call paintComponent when invokelater has ran?

SRC:

Game.java:

```
public class Game extends Window {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Screen gameScreen;
    private boolean game = false;

    public Game() {
        this.gameScreen = new Screen(this);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        super.setGameScreen(this.gameScreen);
        this.game = true;
        this.gameLoop();
    }

    private void gameLoop() {
        while(this.game) {
            this.update();
            this.render();
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        // TODO UPDATRES
    }

    private void render() {
        super.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Game bird = new Game();
                bird.initialize();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Window.java:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    protected Window() {
        super.setTitle("test");
        super.setSize(this.getPerfectSize());
    }

    protected void setGameScreen(JPanel screen) {
        super.add(screen);
        super.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("added");
    }

    private Dimension getPerfectSize() {
        return new Dimension(350, 500);
    }
}
```

Screen.java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Screen extends JPanel {

    private Game game;

    public Screen(Game bird) {
        this.game = bird;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("hey");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post this as a single [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of disconnected code snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because of your infinite loop in gameLoop().

When you execute the Game constructor and initialize() method directly from the main() method, you're on the main thread. The infinite loop is executed on the main thread. When you call repaint(), the EDT is free to call the paintComponent() method.

When you execute the Game constructor and initialize() method from SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), you're putting that code on the EDT. The infinite loop is then executed on the EDT.

Since you're blocking the EDT inside the infinite loop with your approach, that means the EDT isn't free to call the paintComponent() method. It's stuck inside the infinite loop.

The way around this is to put your gameLoop on another thread. Something like:

```
public void initialize() {
    super.setGameScreen(this.gameScreen);
    this.game = true;
    this.startGameLoop();
}

private void startGameLoop() {
    new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(game) {
                update();
                render();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Just make sure that any changes to your gui take place on the EDT. Take a look at the [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) and [Swing concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorials for more detail.

Comment: not by using Swing Timer and most important is usage swing.JWindow instead of awt.Window